The issue with the order of rule execution in iptables


These are the iptables policies auto-generated by the firewalld.service. The iptables policies are matched in top-down order, but testing has found that the second rule " ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0" is not taking effect.

With just iptables -L, you don't see the full details of the rule. Try adding a -v or even better, look at the iptables-save output instead. You'll likely find that rule is about the loopback interface

Please, don't post images of text
